# How to remove a file completely from git repository?

Tags: linux, git

I added `app.apk` into git repository first, and then we decided to remove `app.apk` from git repository. Not only remove it from source code directory but also `.git` directory to reduce the size of git repository.

Suppose I have a commit log like this:

```
commit07 remove `app.apk` from source code directory
commit06 update some files
commit06 update `app.apk` and some files
commit05 fix some bug in source code files
commit04 update `app.apk` and some other source code files
commit03 update some source code files
commit02 add `app.apk` and some other source code files
commit01 init
```

but the size does not shrink. I want to remove `app.apk` from history too.

Which means if I checkout commit04 and `ls app.apk` will say `app.apk not found`

the commit hash is OK to be changed.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Check this GitHub [post on deleting sensitive data from git](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/). This will effectively remove the file from history. I used the filter branch method and worked like a charm.